# Sorted Binary Tree F#

Tags: f#, tree

Hi I have been searching for some good information about how I can make a sorted binary tree datatype in F# but i cant find anything understandable. I have checked the example on msdn-page but i dont get it.

Comment: What have you had so far? We would like to see your (incomplete) datatypes and functions to be able to give advices.

Comment: Since this was closed, I'm just posting some old code I wrote a few years back, which is a AVL tree in F#: http://fssnip.net/2i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for an existing implementation, then [the FSharpX library](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/tree/master/src/FSharpx.Core/DataStructures) has quite a few data structures (including some trees) available. Although I do not think it has a straightforward implementation of a sorted binary tree. You can also access all the .NET collections from F#, but I don't think .NET has a binary tree either. It has [sorted list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx), which might be just fine for you, depending on what you're trying to do.

If you want to implement your own, then you need to start by defining a data type to represent the tree:

```
type SortedTree<'T when 'T : comparison> =
  | Node of SortedTree<'T> * 'T * SortedTree<'T>
  | Leaf of 'T
```

The `Node` element means that all values on the left are smaller than the value stored in the node and all greater (or equal) values are on the right. I added a constraint `'T : comparison` which means that you can only create tree of comparable elements (this is needed in the implementation to sort the tree).

Implementing all the common tree operations is going to be quite a lot of work, but a simple attempt at insertion (that does not keep the tree ballanced in any way) looks like this:

```
let rec insert element tree = 
  match tree with
  | Leaf v when element < v -> Node(Leaf element, v, Leaf v)
  | Leaf v -> Node(Leaf v, element, Leaf element)
  | Node(left, key, right) when element < key -> Node(insert element left, key, right)
  | Node(left, key, right) -> Node(left, key, insert element right)
```

The pattern matching handles 4 interesting cases: When the tree is `Leaf`, you need to build a new node with the new element either on the left or on the right. When the tree is `Node`, then you want to insert to the left or right, depending on the value of the key.

Comment: I really apriciate your answer, really good explaining but how do I know if the function works? I mean its not like a tree shows upp on the screen. Is there also any way I could add a whole list of integers to the tree?

Comment: Leaf doesn't need to have a value attached and this will lead to less duplication without.